# SparkException during DataFrame write on HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm running the following code on a Hadoop cluster using YARN.
It parses some emails and perform sentiment annotation, lastly it writes the outcome DataFrame as a Parquet table on HDFS.  Unfortunately, it keeps failing on the line #66 which is the last dataframe write on HDFS, the error is shown at the bottom. Anyway, I can't explain why it terminates successfully whenever I use a small sample of the dataset.

```scala
object ETLDriver {

    val appName = "ENRON-etl"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val allExtracted = sc.objectFile[(String, Seq[String])](Commons.ENRON_EXTRACTED_TXT)
        // Testing on a sub-sample
        //  val allExtracted = sc.objectFile[(String, Seq[String])](Commons.ENRON_EXTRACTED_TXT).sample(false, 0.01, 42)

        // get custodians from csv file stored in HDFS
        val csv = sc.textFile(Commons.ENRON_CUSTODIANS_CSV_HDFS).map{line => line.split(",")}
        var custodians = sc.broadcast(csv.map{record => Custodian(record(0),record(1),Option(record(2)))}.collect().toSeq)

        // parse emails
        val allParsed: RDD[MailBox] = allExtracted.map { case (mailbox, emails) =>
            val parsedEmails = emails flatMap { email =>
                try Some(EmailParser.parse(email, custodians.value))
                catch {
                    case e: EmailParsingException => None
                }
            }
            MailBox(mailbox, parsedEmails)
        }

        // classify sentiment and save w/o body
        val mailboxesSentiment = allParsed.map { mailbox =>
            // load sentiment annotator pipeline
            val nlpProps = new Properties
            nlpProps.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, lemma, sentiment")
            val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(nlpProps)
            // annotation
            val emailsWithSentiment = mailbox.emails.map { email =>
                val document = new Annotation(email.body)
                pipeline.annotate(document)
                val sentiment = document.get[String](classOf[SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName])
                EmailWithSentiment(email.date, email.from, email.to ++ email.cc ++ email.bcc, email.subject, sentiment)
            }

            MailBoxWithSentiment(mailbox.name, emailsWithSentiment)
        }

        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        val dfFull = allParsed.toDF()   
      dfFull.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(Commons.ENRON_FULL_DATAFRAME)
        val dfSentiment = mailboxesSentiment.toDF()
        dfSentiment.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(Commons.ENRON_SENTIMENT_DATAFRAME)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
AM Container for appattempt_1456482988572_5307_000001 exited with exitCode: 15
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://head05.custer_url:8088/cluster/app/application_1456482988572_5307Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1456482988572_5307_01_000001
Exit code: 15
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is lsde03
main : requested yarn user is lsde03
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
Failing this attempt
```

Longer log [here](http://pastebin.com/fXmcjWEH)

Comment: Can you note which line is line 66, since StackOverflow doesn't have line numbers. This one? `dfSentiment.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(Commons.ENRON_SENTIMENT_DATAFRAME)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line numbers in Spark can often be pretty unhelpful.  They will usually point to the line that triggered the job, not the problem, so it is usually some `save` or `collect` operation.

In the log you linked is an `ExecutorLostFailure`.  It is not clear why and I've found that usually when Spark does not give a reason, memory is a good place to start.   How big is the data you are broadcasting? You may want to check your memory settings.  For Spark on YARN, this is as good article to understand.

http://www.wdong.org/wordpress/blog/2015/01/08/spark-on-yarn-where-have-all-my-memory-gone/

Hope this helps

Comment: The total size of the files loaded into ```allExtracted``` is 3.3G according to HDFS. Thanks for the link, unfortunately I don't have access to the Spark/Hadoop configs, I think I can probably just send some params with the ```spark-submit```. I've tried to execute to run with plenty of resources and it still fails (```spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 480 --executor-memory 12G --executor-cores 4 --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 6G [......]```). Anyway, if I comment the sentiment extraction (lines marked ```<<<``` [here](http://pastebin.com/9zsLgPpF)) it works